# A region of my ROC curve is below the random line, how to modify the confusion matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, roc

In the following roc curve when the threshold is low the roc_curve goes below the random line why does this happen?
The confusion matrix looks like this,
my question is which of the following elements (TP,FP,TN,FN) in the confusion matrix should be increased or decreased in order to get the roc_curve over the random line?

[image: ROC Curve]

```
            Predicted
            Neg   Pos

Actual Neg  1656  860
Actual Pos  145  331
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminaries**

predict_proba, called on your model object, returns **predicted probability** of event=1 for each row of your data.

**ROC**

When plotting ROC, corresponding method sorts your data with respect to **predicted probability** of event=1 in descending order. ROC tells you precisely what combinations of TPR and FPR you can achieve with your model predictions.

What this shape of ROC says is:

1. **predicted probability** of event=1, generated by your model, matches **true probability** of event=1 ***better*** than random assignment (represented by "random line") for about 85% of your data. Precisely speaking, these 85% are the 85% rows with highest **predicted probability** of event=1.
2. **predicted probability** of event=1, generated by your model, matches **true probability** of event=1 ***worse*** than random assignment (represented by "random line") for about 15% of your data. Precisely speaking, these 15% are the 15% rows with lowest **predicted probability** of event=1.

I have taken values 85% and 15% from your chart: this is my eyeball estimate of point where ROC crosses the diagonal ("random line") and should be considered illustrative only.
One possible reason for such phenomenon: this might be result of overfitting related to one-hot encoded categorical feature, whose categories "behave" differently for various sub-populations of your data set. You might want to experiment with excluding some of the variables before fitting the model and look for improvements in shape of your ROC.

**Confusion Matrix**

Confusion matrix results from the same **predicted probability** of event=1, generated by your model. Single confusion matrix is related to a specific **predicted probability** threshold for assigning single row either prediction=1 or prediction=0. Single confusion matrix is represented by a single point at ROC, so you can't actually manipulate ROC shape by manipulating confusion matrix elements. You should reason the other way around: ROC shape somehow tells you what confusion matrices are achievable by your model.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually I am using embedding instead of one-hot encoding,  and by checking the loss graph of train vs. validation there is no overfitting. by the way, I am using one dataset for training and validation and another dataset to test the model on it (as it is shown in the roc). regarding the information that I provided could you please provide me more insights? @Juan regarding the confusion matrix,  If you were to solve this issue how would you change the performance of the model in order to not get that curve (e.g. penalize class pos for neg or viceversa)

Comment: @MostafaAlishahi Could you present separate ROC curve for your train data, separate for your validation data and separate for your test data? What you could actually do, is to play with features employed by the model: try to exclude some features, starting e.g. from identifying: 1) features having non-monotonic relation with target variable, and excluding such feature, 2) most correlated pairs of features, and excluding one of the pair.